# Bower using old registry instead of new

Tags: bower

My bower has just started giving errors when I do a grunt build.  In particular, I am seeing errors like:

```
Warning: Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular failed with 502 Use --force to continue.
```

Doing some research, it looks like the registry server has changed from bower.herokuapp.com to registry.bower.io.  However, my bower is still hitting the old server.

My bower is updated to the latest version: 1.8.4.
I've cleared my bower cache, just in case.

Not sure what to do next.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to specify the registry locally in my .bowerrc file, but I would still like to know how to get it to hit the new registry by default.

```
{
    "directory": "app/bower_components",
    "registry": {
        "search": [
            "https://registry.bower.io"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: facing the exact same error. just updating to 1.8.4 helped for me, though!